# PHP Invisible character(s) in a string taken from a txt file

Tags: php

I've been trying to compare text taken from a .txt file to text in a php script.

http://puu.sh/93dJ9.png

The output is:
Leerlingenorkest
Leerlingenorkest
94.117647058824

The first output is entered in an html form.
The second output is taken from the .txt file.
They look exactly the same to me but for some reason similar_text says they are only ~94% the same. Are there invisible characters taken from the txt file as well or something?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `echo` if you are in a developing environment to really see what is going on

Comment: Use `var_dump` in such case to see what exactly you getting.

Comment: You can use [`Hexdump`](https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump) to analyze the strings.

Comment: Maybe line endings? Try doing `str_replace("/n","",str_replace("/r","",$text))` on both text variables.

Comment: Using bin2hex I do get 2 different results however it doesn't seem to be /n or /r. this: http://puu.sh/93ein.png gives this result: http://puu.sh/93ekk.png

Comment: var_dump does show a difference: http://puu.sh/93euf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comment use [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [Hexdump](https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump) to get your real string output if it contains any special characters or unwanted spaces.

I assume you're getting an unwanated spaces while reading a string from a file Use [**trim**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove that spaces and see if it works,

```
//$str2 = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $str2); Try this too
similar_text(trim($str1),trim($str2),$percent1);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6IZSok)**.

Comment: Using trim() on the string taken from the txt file seems to do the trick!